# Drupal 7 site. Strange errors

Tags: drupal

Am developing a drupal site online.
The hosters had a "small ddos attack" on their server and asked me to restore my most recent backup. This I did but the ddblock video on the frontage does not work and all my views continue to show  "All changes are stored temporarily...". Even if I save them, I get the message "your view has been saved" but the other message continues to show.
I have now restored an earlier backup and there is no change.
Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2):

Could be a lot of things:

- Did you clear your cache?
- Did you update modules after the date the backups where created?
- Are the backups actually complete, and were they imported correctly?
- Did you try setting up your Drupal website on a local dev machine as to rule out problems with your "small ddos attack" host? :) Actually that would be my second suggestion after clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Following on chrizzler's answer
*Did you try setting up your Drupal website on a local dev machine...?* would have been my first answer.

You could use [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) to save your website's state, depending on your site's size you could use the [Backup & Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module to backup/restore your database.

Check that the errors don't appear on your local dev site, then you can safely update your online version, using GIT & any database backup you may have.

If problems appear online, it may not be a Drupal issue[